# Jupyter stuck in pip install

Tags: python, pip, jupyter

In my windows 10 laptop, in Jupypter notebook cell, the below command is stuck for hours without any movement/error?

```
!pip install torch
```

Where should I look for logs to find the issue? I see other python commands are working if I kill the cell and run. Any clues?

Comment: This is unrelated to AIML and so you might want to remove that tag.

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to install torch in `pip` environment, use this

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install torch
```

- for `pip3`

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip3 install torch
```

- If you want to install torch in `conda` environment, use this

```
import sys
!conda install --yes --prefix {sys.prefix} torch
```

[For further knowledge](https://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2017/12/05/installing-python-packages-from-jupyter/)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are encountering arises when conda and pip are running parallely.

```
conda install pytorch torchvision -c pytorch
```

should do the job. If not, try doing

```
pip3 install https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu/torch-1.0.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
```

You can also go to the official website https://pytorch.org/ and download from there.